# building a string recursively in java using a Binary search trees data

Tags: java

I am trying to build a string recursively but the method returns the string before the recursive method is done.
What code should do is when toStringHelper is called it should create a string of all of the elements in the binary search tree in order. I can do this with a print statement with the given code but don't know how to make it into a string that gets returned.

```
  protected static String toStringHelper(BSTNode current, String result) {

    if (current != null) {
      toStringHelper(current.getLeft(), result);
      result += current.getData().toString() + "\n";
      toStringHelper(current.getRight(), result);
      
    }
    
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the recursive calls to `toStringHelper`.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just append directly to result? It should build the same.

```java
protected static String toStringHelper(BSTNode current, String result) {

    if (current != null) {
      if(current.getLeft() != null) result += toStringHelper(current.getLeft(), result);
      result += current.getData().toString() + "\n";
      if(current.getRight() != null) result += toStringHelper(current.getRight(), result);
      
    }
    
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Yes isn't that essentially what I am doing? My issue lies in how to return the full result. Because the return statement runs when current does equal null.

Comment: @charms That is the same structure as you were doing it, but in your code, you weren't using the returned result of the left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Actually String result argument is not needed . You can check below code .

```
protected static String toStringHelper(BSTNode current)
    {
        if (current == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        String result="";
        result += toStringHelper(current.getLeft());
        result += current.getData().toString() + "\n";
        result += toStringHelper(current.getRight());
        return result;
    }
```

This is how it is called from main()

```
 BSTNode root = new BSTNode();
        root.setData("Root");
        root.setLeft(new BSTNode(null, null, "Left"));
        root.setRight(new BSTNode(null, null, "Right"));
        String res = toStringHelper(root);
        System.out.println("Res is " + res);
```

Here is the o/p

```
Res is Left
Root
Right
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @charms plz accept the answer if you find it correct .